# How can I tell if a USB C charger is compatible with my device?

Tags: battery, power, charging

I have two different laptops which have USB-C chargers, both have 65W chargers, but the voltages and amperages are slightly different. How can I tell if a USB C charger is compatible with my device? Can I use the existing charger as a basis of what it needs?

Comment: What are the voltage and current specs on the laptop stickers and what are the voltage and current capacities of the chargers.  This general question about charger compatibility has been asked many times.

Comment: I haven't been able to find an existing information on USB C chargers. If you have one available I would love to look at it.

One of my 65W chargers is:
20V⎓3.25A, 
15V⎓3A, 
9V⎓2A, 
5V⎓2A.

The other 65W charger is:
5V, 9V, 15V⎓3A, 
20V⎓3.25A

Answer (score 0):

Generally what you need to worry about is the voltage and currents - I would not use them just because of the risk of over-volting the laptop. I don't think (to my knowledge) under-volting is that much of an issue, but its still not very good. Too low of a current is also bad as your laptop will suffer charger times, but a larger current by the supply doesn't pose any problem - your laptop will take as much as needed. It also depends on the pinout configurations of the power adapter (below)

To answer the question, I would NOT use them unless you absolutely have to. Going back to using USB-C as a connector, certain devices use different pins for charging (example being oneplus phones use another pin for charging) so it may or may not work at all - in a very bad case, its possible that the USB charger may deliver power on the data pins (for proprietary systems maybe?) which can be disastrous. Again, this is unlikely, and I am unsure of the USB power protocol, and your main issue here is the voltage mismatch. If its different by perhaps 0.5 to 2 volts I would say it is worth a shot, but if anything starts to smell or the light doesnt turn on as it normally would, then immediately disconnect. Then, try and find a replacement adapter that has the correct voltage and current.